# Best practice to index neo4j edges

Tags: indexing, neo4j

Consider I have a graph model where users can like items and the time of actual like is recorded in an edge:

```
(:USER {name:Bill})-[:ACTION {type:like, time:1234567890}]->(:ITEM {name:Porsche})
```

Now I want to select all :ACTIONs of a particular :USER ordered by 'time' very fast. I don't need :ACTIONs of all :USERs sorted, only for a particular :USER. The simple solution which can be thinked of is indexing, where for each :USER, there is an index for :ACTION by 'time' field. The problem is that it seems neo4j doesn't allow such advanced index manipulations.

I can think of a workaround which is supported by neo4j

```
Model - (:USER {id:54321,name:Bill})-[:DOES]->(:ACTION:USER_54321_ACTION {type:like, time:1234567890})-[:REFERS_TO]->(:ITEM {name:Porsche})
Index - CREATE INDEX ON :USER_54321_ACTION(time)
```

But I don't like such approach, especially because it uses generated labels, and 2 redundant elements.

Is there a better solution for my task using neo4j?

ps: If you are familiar with DynamoDB, what I'm seeking from neo4j is 'hash' and 'range' index concepts, where 'range' index is created for each particular 'hash' key and not for all items in the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option 1) from @stdob-- points into the right direction. However I'd it a little bit differently:

- following stdob-- we have "action" nodes with time property connecting the user with an item. But the action don't have labels, nor indexes. Rationale: Indexes are always on per label level. So it's not very efficient to query all actions to find just the few specific to a given user.
- two subsequent action nodes are additionally connected with each other using a `PREV` relationship
- the most recent action is connected to the user using a `LAST_ACTION` relationship. So you have a linked list of all action nodes preordered by time. The entry point is the `LAST_ACTION` relationship (which of course needs to be moved over when a new action gets added)

Comment: Linked List - a great idea!

Comment: Really nice idea )) This is the power of graph ) Thx.

Answer (score 0):

1) I think that the change in the model the right solution. But I have a little changed your version:

```
Model - (:USER {id:54321,name:Bill})
          -[:DOES]->
        (:ACTION:ACTION_LIKE {time:1234567890})
          -[:REFERS_TO]->
        (:ITEM {name:Porsche})
Index - CREATE INDEX ON :ACTION(time)
        CREATE INDEX ON :ACTION_LIKE(time)
```

2) If not, look in the direction of legacy index.

3) Alternatively, use the [`APOC`](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures#index-queries) for Neo4j.

Comment: Hi stdob, thx for the reply. First solution looks good, but it seems, that there will be created one ACTION_LIKE index, which will be used for all users, and I'd like indices to be created per user to avoid index update throttling when different users 'like' something at the same time.